# importing a package from within another package in python

Tags: python, python-import

Please assume the following project structure:

```
/project
  /packages
    /files
      __init__.py
      fileChecker.py
    /hasher
      __init__.py
      fileHash.py
    mainProject.py
    /test
```

I would like to get access to the module `fileChecker.py` from within the module `fileHash.py`.
This is some kind of global package.

One way is to append paths to `sys.path`.
[Is this PYTHONPATH by the way?]

What would be a solution when distributing the project?

- Same as above? --> But then there could be paths to modules with the
  same name in `PYTHONPATH`?
- Is `setuptools` doing all the work?

How can I achieve it in a nice and clean way?

Thanks alot.

---

**Update:**

*Also see my answer below*
--> when calling `fileHash.py` (including an import like from files `import fileChecker`) directly from within its package directory, the project's path needs to be added to `sys.path` (**described below**).

**Test cases** situated within `/test` (see structure above) also need the path added to `sys.path`, when called from within `/test`.

Comment: Maybe I shoul add, that I try to call fileHash.py directly. There is no prblem in calling mainProject.py.

Comment: in `fileChecker.py`: `from project.packages.hasher import fileHash`, assuming you use absolute imports (Python 3.x or `from __future__ import absolute_import`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks mguijarr.

I found a solution here on stackoverflow:
source:
[How to fix "Attempted relative import in non-package" even with __init__.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py/27876800#27876800)

when I am in the project folder /project, I can call the module like this:

```
python -m packages.files.fileHash (no .py here, because it is a package)
```

This is wokring well.
In this case PYTHONPATH is known and the import can look like this:

```
from packages.files import fileChecker
```

If it is not called directly, but from within the package directory in my case /packages/hasher --> setting the PYTHONPATH is needed:

```
if __package__ is None:
    import sys
    from os import path
    sys.path.append( path.dirname( path.dirname( path.abspath(__file__) ) ) )
    from packages.files import fileChecker
else:
    from packages.files import fileChecker
```

The important thing for me here is, that the path to include is the PROJECT path.

The code snippet above(the last one) already includes the case describes both cases (called as package and directly).

Thanks alot for your help.

**Update**:

1. Just to make my answer more complete

Python adds the current path to the PYTHONPATH automatically when doing

```
python fileHash.py
```

Another option, in addition to the one above, is to set the PYTHONPATH when running the program like this

```
PYTHONPATH=/path/to/project python fileHash.py
```

2. I gained some experience, I would like to share:

   - I don't run modules from within their directories anymore.
   - Starting the app, running tests or sphinx or pylint or whatever is all done from the project directory.
   - This ensures that the project directory is contained in the python path and all packages, modules are found without doing additional stuff on imports.
   - The only place I still set the python path to the project folder using sys.path is in my setup.py in order to make codeship work.

Still, in my opinion this is somehow not an easy matter and I find myself reflecting the PYTHONPATH often enough :)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found another solution, quite intuitive, no sys path or anything needed: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/python/python-package

And then do what they explain in ''Install a Package Globally''.

In your case, put the "setup.py" file in the packages directory and add the two packages:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(name='mypackage',
version='0.1',
description='Testing installation of Package',
url='#',
author='malhar',
author_email='mlathkar@gmail.com',
license='MIT',
packages=['files', 'hasher'], ## here the names
zip_safe=False)
```